# VBA Count Range Name

Tags: excel, vba

Can some one review de code? It´s not working on microsoft 365

```
Sub countNamedRanges()
    Dim nm As Name
    Dim nameCount As Integer
    'loop through all names in the workbook
    For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If Split(nm.RefersTo, "!")(0) = "=Sheet1" Then nameCount = nameCount + 1
    Next
    Debug.Print nameCount
End Sub
```

Erro: Insufficient memory

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the If Split() line. Does it work for the first iterations before the insufficient memory error happens? Or does it fail right from the start? The code works for me, so it's probably not the code causing the problem.

Comment: Inside your For Each loop, try adding a line `Debug.Print nameCount,nm` that should at least tell you how many times it runs successfully and point you to the name that is causing the problem.

Comment: if finally fix the error use> If InStr(1, nm.RefersTo, "=SHEET12") > 0 Then....  instead of: If Split(nm.RefersTo, "!")(0) = "=Sheet1" then... The second one is 46% slower

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is working on my end.

Maybe your worksheet has a different name? Can you verify that `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).CodeName` is in fact `Sheet1`?

If you pause in the For Loop, what's the value for `nm.RefersTo`?